# How do I auto-create a code snippet in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, interface, code-snippets

I'm trying to create an interface that automatically implements a fully typed out method in VB.Net

However, I can't figure out how to do it.

I wanna do something that's similar to what happens when you implement IDisposable, where it gives you the full function, including codes and comments.

I know how to make a code snippet and how to use the tab shortcut, but how can I make the code snippet automatically appear when I implement my own interface?

Answer (score 0):

This is easily done in just three steps:

1. Buy ReSharper
2. Create a live template to do this
3. Profit!

Code snippets are a huge pain in the neck to work with for even trivial tasks.

Comment: While that can be true, if he has a pretty basic understanding of XML then I think he should be able to do it.